# Can I somehow use 0x notation with long

Tags: java

Working with SMPP protocol I used `long` to represent values of `system_id` field of type `unsigned int` (4 bytes). In protocol itself field values are specified in hexademical format.
So I wanted to preserve it in my code. While trying to compare the variable value i wrote:

```
long id = ...;
//...
if(id == 0x80000009){...}
```

And found out that java interprets `0x80000009` as `int`, which is signed 4 byte int, so an overflow takes place and the comparison fails:

```
id         == 2147483657
0x80000009 ==-2147483639
```

Then I tried explicit type casting, i.e. `id == (long)0x80000009` - same result.
Then I declared variable like this:

```
static final long bind_transceiver_resp = 0x80000009;
```

But it's still an overflowed `int` value.

So is there a way to use `0x` notation with values greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put an L on the end of the literal. 0x80000009L is 2147483657.  Note that a lower case l works too, but I don't recommend it because in many fonts, it looks like the number one.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I would also greatly appreciate a link to a wider description of possible literal usages

Comment: Perhaps the page at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html will meet your needs (although I'm surprised that it doesn't mention octal).